# Problem with difficult caclulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, cross-browser

Is it possible to get different result in different browsers with some math operation?
E.g. something like that

```
if(vote!=0)total_reiting = Math.round((full_reiting/vote)*100)/100;
var star_widht = full_reiting*17/vote;
$('#raiting_votes').width(star_widht);
$('#raiting_info b').append(total_reiting);
```

Mb its bettter to use back-end calculation? Or its better in any case to hadle logic on beck-end?

Comment: Are you seeing different results in different browsers?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you would get different results on a different browser, although the nature of floating point and rounding makes it possible that you'd get different results under a different implementation.  I just think it's very unlikely you'll ever see that.

Answer (score 1):

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is an open source JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all modern browsers.

Comment: MathJax has nothing to do with calculations.  It's for rendering equations in LaTeX fashion.